# How to create a button like the picture

Tags: android, button, android-button, material-components-android, android-vectordrawable

I want to create a shape for buttons like this picture but I don't know how to use shape for creating a button like the picture.

[image: button picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below background vector drawable for something like
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="80"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
    <group android:name="rotationGroup">
        <path
            android:pathData="M 5,5 L 75,5 75,25 12,25 5,16 5,5"
            android:strokeWidth="1"
            android:fillColor="#44008080"
            android:strokeColor="#008080"
            android:trimPathStart="0"
            android:trimPathEnd="1" />
    </group>

</vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

OR you can just add the picture as the background.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pic1" />
</selector>
```

[image]

[image]

---

Just define a layout for the button as the background insert, and you can change the effect you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ff000000" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This shape just create a simple rectangle

Comment: HI@H Hooshyar i updated my code,pls kindly refer,hope this could help

Comment: Thanks a lot but this is not like the picture that I sent in my question. My picture doesn't have any radius

Comment: hi friend,i just updated my code again,pls kindly refer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SVG file and set it as background. Change it as per your requirement (color and path)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="80"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
    <group android:name="rotationGroup">
        <path
            android:pathData="M 5,5 L 75,5 75,25 15,25 5,5"
            android:strokeWidth="1"
            android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
            android:trimPathStart="0"
            android:trimPathEnd="1" />
    </group>

</vector>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but this XML doesn't draw a line in left side. I don't know anything about XML that creates SVG so please tell me how should I make fix that to draw another line in left side like the picture

Answer (score 0):

You can search for .svg format of button like that, convert it into xml coding using online convertors and use that xml code in your application. Then you simply have to refer that xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom shape as background.
Just use the `MaterialButton` with **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/..."
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CustomShape"
    />
```

with:

```
<style name="CustomShape">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]